# Sorting an array by a number string (Python 3.4.2)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, python-3.x

I have been trying to sort an array that looks like this:

```
sav = [['Name: ', 'Alex', 'Score: ', '2'], ['Name: ', 'Josh, 'Score: ', '3'], ['Name: ', 'James', 'Score: ', '1']]
```

so that it appears as:

```
sav = [['Name: ', 'James', 'Score: ', '1'], ['Name: ', 'Alex, 'Score: ', '2'], ['Name: ', 'Josh', 'Score: ', '3']]
```

This would be sorting by the `[3]` index but as the number is a string I am not sure how to do this. (This may look like a duplicate question but I have looked around and not been able to find an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following `lambda` as the sort key:

```
>>> sorted(sav, key=lambda x: int(x[3]))
[['Name: ', 'James', 'Score: ', '1'],
 ['Name: ', 'Alex', 'Score: ', '2'],
 ['Name: ', 'Josh', 'Score: ', '3']]
```

The `lambda` function here picks out the element at index 3 from each list and treats it as integer (using `int`). The list is sorted by these integers.

If left as strings, you'd get odd results when sorting since strings are sorted in lexicographical order. For example, `'12' < '8'`.

This returns a sorted copy of the list `sav` - you can rebind the name to the sorted list:

```
sav = sorted(sav, key=lambda x: int(x[3]))
```

Comment: When I try this the output is exactly the same (even though I looked at your code and it looked like it would work)

Comment: @zeldor You need to say `sav = sorted(...` so you assign the sorted list back to your variable. Or use `sort(sav, key=...)` to sort in place.

Comment: Thanks both of you, that worked. Turns out all of the solutions I had previously tried just needed 'sav =' !!